# NGINX change <?php to <?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I have installed nginx in ubuntu, and apparently have a newer version of php, which forces me to put `<? Php` in all websites if not read, I have a fairly large and serious system problem updating all as I can do to remove that restriction and using the simple `<?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure it on your php.ini. Nginx is not related, it is a web server.

Enable the short tag modifying your php.ini with this command

`sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

and add this line

`short_open_tag = On`

Close nano and restart nginx with this command

`sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: You probably want to restart `php-fpm` (or whatever else is running PHP) since nginx doesn't run PHP at all.